# change grid column order in mobile mode

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one requirement where i have to show four grid column in desktop mode like in this [image] which is correct.

For that i used below html code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            2
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when i see the same in mobile this shows like below:

```html
1
2
3
4
```

But my requirement is it should show like below in mobile:

```html
1 2
3 4
```

How could i do the same using above html code?

Comment: That is because on the mobile bit you are using the XS class meaning on all small devices it's going to be full-width. Change it to col-xs-6 to get the result you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-xs-6` instead of `col-xs-12`
See [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            2
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked for me. I am upvoting your answer.